# Why do I get multiple windows messages of same kind?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to respond to some windows <strike>and application</strike> messages, but I get them multiple times.

For example, I write the following code to show a message box when the date of system is changed using WM_TIMECHANGE. WMTimeChange is executed more than once, and I see multiples (most times two or three) messageboxes one behind another. Maybe, I am missing something?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage) ; message WM_TIMECHANGE;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    showmessage('Date/Time has changed!');
end;

end.
```

Testing in Windows XP.

EDIT: Just to clarify, my intention is understand **WHY** that happen and not how to get around the multiple calls. Anyway, if an answer to that is not possible, I will probably accept one answer to the later.

EDIT2: Removed Delphi Tag as it seems not a Delphi issue.

Comment: Well, how are you causing the time to change? Why *shouldn't* the message be sent multiple times?

Comment: @RobKennedy double click in clock, change the year( let's say from 2012 to 2013), click 'ok' button. I've changed the year only once, so I expect only one WM_TIMECHANGE.

Comment: @EMBarbosa: I think that the operating system *guarantees* that the message is sent (at least once) every time the time is changed. But I don't think it guarantees that it is sent *exactly* once. After all, perhaps the GUI operation you described, at a technical level, corresponds to three changes to the system date/time data.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: why three changes?

Comment: I don't know. But it is not unimaginable. If you work a lot with low-level programming you learn that there might be a lot of subtleties everywhere.

Comment: Well, it seems that you get the message multiple times. Not much you can do about that other than suck it down and write your code in a way to be resilient to this.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: "If you work a lot with low-level programming you learn that there might be a lot of subtleties everywhere". The sad part is that you are right.

Comment: @EMBarbosa: You could ask Raymond next time he makes an inquiry for topics to discuss.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes. To be resilient to this I could put a flag in the form. When WMTimeChange is called I test if true, set to false and execute, changing it back to true at the end. As the user would be prompted to take an action, it will take the necessary time to the additional WM_TIMECHANGE messages got ignored. It's the most simple way that pulled out of my head by now.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Are you reading my mind? Stop now! :)

Comment: Yes that should get the job done

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A true/false could not work if all messages are sent when the process is already finished. So it will depend on the processing time. My answer with a time threshold may work better. You have to manually set the time using the Windows UI - so it will not likely be made often.

Comment: @Arnaud Time can be set programatically. It certainly does not have to be done from the UI. The idea of EMBarbosa is that his/her program will show a dialog and by the time the user has responded to the dialog the other `WM_TIMECHANGE` messages will have been processed.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: David is right. The user will not take an action with less than one sec. But, my intention on the question was, at first, **why** this happen, and not _how to get around it_. I will edit the question to clarify this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. It sounds like that Windows is sending the WM_TIMECHANGE message several times.

So you can just add a small time-hysteresis comparison to let your message be triggered only once per a 1% of day, i.e. more or less 15 minutes:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  protected
    FWMTimeChangeTimeStamp: TDateTime;
    procedure WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage) ; message WM_TIMECHANGE;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Now-FWMTimeChangeTimeStamp>0.01 then 
  begin
    showmessage('Date/Time has changed!');
    FWMTimeChangeTimeStamp := Now; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Sertac Who says that you won't be able to process the first one before the second one gets posted?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It seems that *several* messages are sent. Using `message WM_TIMECHANGE` event handler will let all messages be processed. The 15 minutes threshold I implemented in my answer will allow to process only the first one, and ignore the following up to 15 minutes. If 15 minutes is not good, you can just change 0.01 into  0.001 or 0.0002 for a smaller period.

Comment: Arnaud, I was rather thinking that acting on the last one could have a significance, if you're to read the time for instance and if the OS changes it in between posts. But I guess @David is right..

Comment: Don't forget to initialize FWMTimeChangeTimeStamp. Cause you never know if the computer time would not be between 1899/12/30 12:00 A.M and 1899/12/30 12:15 A.M when user start the application. Maybe depleted CMOS battery related problems... who knows.

Comment: I'm accepting this, cause is so far the best way to handle this. But I am still looking for the WHY.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of what I've used in my case to be resilient to this behavior. But as said in comments, will only work if the user take time to answer the application. So, Arnaud Bounchez is a better approach to general use. Only don't forget to initialize the FWMTimeChangeStamp to something that is different from current computer clock.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage) ; message WM_TIMECHANGE;
  private
    isTimeChangeEventShowing: Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  isTimeChangeEventShowing := false
end;

procedure TForm1.WMTimeChange(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if not isTimeChangeEventShowing then
  begin
    isTimeChangeEventShowing := true;
    showmessage('Date/Time has changed!');
    isTimeChangeEventShowing := false;
  end;
end;

end.
```